# ML.NET Tensorflow Image clasification crashes with SEHException when run in Azure

Tags: c#, tensorflow, azure-web-app-service, ml.net

I'm using ML.NET tensorflow in asp.net core C# app for image background removal (similarly to how it is implemented here https://github.com/susheelsk/image-background-removal, https://github.com/OPHoperHPO/image-background-remove-tool).
Tensorflow model used is DeepLabV3 xception_model http://download.tensorflow.org/models/deeplabv3_pascal_train_aug_2018_01_04.tar.gz
When run locally it works without errors (at least I was not able to reproduce it locally).
But when running app service in Azure, sometimes it starts to crash with SEHException on calling PredictionEnginePool Predict method:

---

System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception. at Tensorflow.c_api.TF_SessionRun(IntPtr session, TF_Buffer* run_options, TF_Output[] inputs, IntPtr[] input_values, Int32 ninputs, TF_Output[] outputs, IntPtr[] output_values, Int32 noutputs, IntPtr[] target_opers, Int32 ntargets, IntPtr run_metadata, IntPtr status) at Microsoft.ML.TensorFlow.TensorFlowUtils.Runner.Run() at Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TensorFlowTransformer.Mapper.UpdateCacheIfNeeded(Int64 position, ITensorValueGetter[] srcTensorGetters, String[] activeOutputColNames, OutputCache outputCache) at Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TensorFlowTransformer.Mapper.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<MakeGetter>b__4(VBuffer`1& dst) at Microsoft.ML.Data.TypedCursorable`1.TypedRowBase.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`1.b__0(TRow row) at Microsoft.ML.Data.TypedCursorable`1.TypedRowBase.FillValues(TRow row) at Microsoft.ML.Data.TypedCursorable`1.RowImplementation.FillValues(TRow row) at Microsoft.ML.PredictionEngineBase`2.FillValues(TDst prediction) at Microsoft.ML.PredictionEngine`2.Predict(TSrc example, TDst& prediction) at Microsoft.ML.PredictionEngineBase`2.Predict(TSrc example) at Microsoft.Extensions.ML.PredictionEnginePoolExtensions.Predict[TData,TPrediction](PredictionEnginePool`2 predictionEnginePool, String modelName, TData example) at...

---

How can I investigate it more deeply to get more insights on this?
What can be the reason of such issue?

And one more note: issue disappears after restarting of service and its web jobs.

Comment: Same exception happened on Azure Function app hosted in Cloud. Raised an issue on dotnet/machinelearning. https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5361

Answer (score 0):

> How can I investigate it more deeply to get more insights on this?

You might be able to get meaningful error code

[`SEHException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception?view=netcore-3.1) is derived from [`ExternalException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception?view=netcore-3.1) and has an [`ErrorCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception.errorcode?view=netcore-3.1) property which is just a `HRESULT` defined in `Winerror.h`

Common error values are located here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/common-hresult-values

Comment: Yes, I've checked that error code (it's in exception stack trace above).  
SEHException (0x80004005) - E_FAIL Unspecified failure. But it doesn't provide a lot of information to me.